# Json encode returning full page rather than just array

Tags: php, json

Here is my php file

```
<?php 
    require("common.php"); 
    if(empty($_SESSION['Id'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: login.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        include 'top.php';          

        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Id = :id");
        $stmt->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
?>
```

When I do a console log in my js file I get the whole html file rather than just my array.

Here is my success function

```
success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
{ 
    console.log(data);
    var id = data[0]['Id'];//get name
    alert(id);   //get name
}
```

I need to alert the Id but at the moment I can only return < (refering to the first char of my html page).

Comment: If this is an AJAX response, you should probably `echo` the `json_encode()` and then `exit`.

Comment: I suspect the HTML is coming from `top.php`. Don't use that in a script that's just supposed to return JSON.

Comment: Possibly several problems here. What is in `top.php`? If you include that and it has HTML, you are outputting that before you might be outputting the json (which you aren't even echoing). Is there an `Id` value in the SESSION? If not, you will get the contents of your login page back.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. top.php was causing the issue!